# MySQL - How to Cast a datetime from an rss feed

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, casting

I'm importing an rss feed into MySQL 5.1 via wget and LOAD DATA INFILE.

This is all working well, but, I'm having problems converting the date & time in the rss feed to a datetime col in mysql.

An example date from the feed is:

Sat, 19 Jan 2013 11:10:19 GMT

Any ideas how I can cast or convert this?

Thanks

J.

Comment: `Str_to_Date()` function can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `STR_TO_DATE`

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_STRING,'%a, %d %b %Y %h:%i:%s')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd656/1)

OTHER SOURCE

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [Date Formats](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 2):

How about this? using [`str_to_Date`](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php):

```
STR_TO_DATE('rss_date', '%y-%m-%d')
```